# Android VoIP Linphone

Tags: android, voip

I used Liblinphone library for Android app. Recently, I found an issue about this library. In terms of Samsung A5 with Android 8.0, the microphone volume is pretty low and has echo. but for same device with Android 7.0 and even other android phones like HuaWei and Samsung S7, microphone volume is good and no echo. Anyone encountered the similar issue?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for taking the time to ask a question, but as currently written, your question seems to be a bit broad. Please modify/update so that the issue is more specific.

Comment: Some devices have an integrated echo canceller i.e. "This device (LGE/Nexus 5X/msm8992) declares it has a built-in echo canceller", as reported by Mediastreamer (part of liblinphone). An echo canceller operates on the mic volume, I think. So different echo cancellers could explain differences in the audio volume. The presence (or not) of echo can by explained in terms of efficiency of the echo canceller.